# Injecting method calls using Mono.Cecil draws InvalidProgramException in constructor

Tags: c#, code-injection, mono.cecil

I use Mono.Cecil to inject two method calls into a constructor. Somehow the construction always fails with the following error:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Networking.ServerController:.ctor (): IL_0028: callvirt  0x0600017f
```

What I basically do is to inject a method call to the following method (from two base-classes above) for every `stfld` while passing the name of the method (without class) and the current field value (boxed) as object:

```
protected void LocalNetworkVariableChange(string variableName, object value) {
  // Fails no matter what i put here
}
```

The IL code before injection:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: newobj System.Void System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.UInt16,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
IL_0006: stfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.UInt16,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByClientId
IL_000b: ldarg.0
IL_000c: newobj System.Void System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Util.NuID,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
IL_0011: stfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Util.NuID,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByPlayerId
IL_0016: ldarg.0
IL_0017: call System.Void Networking.PeerController`1<Networking.ServerController>::.ctor()
IL_001c: nop
IL_001d: ret
```

After Injection:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: newobj System.Void System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.UInt16,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
IL_0006: stfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.UInt16,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByClientId
IL_000b: ldarg.0
IL_000c: newobj System.Void System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Util.NuID,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
IL_0011: stfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Util.NuID,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByPlayerId
IL_0016: ldarg.0
IL_0017: call System.Void Networking.PeerController`1<Networking.ServerController>::.ctor()
IL_001c: nop
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0000: ldstr "_connectedPlayersByClientId"
IL_0000: ldfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.UInt16,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByClientId
IL_0000: callvirt System.Void Networking.NetworkBehaviour::LocalNetworkVariableChange(System.String,System.Object)
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0000: ldstr "_connectedPlayersByPlayerId"
IL_0000: ldfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Util.NuID,Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByPlayerId
IL_0000: callvirt System.Void Networking.NetworkBehaviour::LocalNetworkVariableChange(System.String,System.Object)
IL_001d: ret
```

(!) The labels in front of the instructions are updated lazy when writing out the instructions to file via Mono.Cecil. This is why the seem to have a wrong offset and map all to `IL_0000`.

The final IL code looks like this:

```
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // Code size       62 (0x3e)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<uint16,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stfld      [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<uint16,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByClientId
    IL_000b:  ldarg.0
    IL_000c:  newobj     instance void [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<class Util.NuID,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer>::.ctor()
    IL_0011:  stfld      [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<class Util.NuID,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByPlayerId
    IL_0016:  ldarg.0
    IL_0017:  call       instance void class Networking.PeerController`1<class Networking.ServerController>::.ctor()
    IL_001c:  nop
    IL_001d:  ldarg.0
    IL_001e:  ldstr      "_connectedPlayersByClientId"
    IL_0023:  ldfld      [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<uint16,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByClientId
    IL_0028:  callvirt   instance void Networking.NetworkBehaviour::LocalNetworkVariableChange(string,
                                                                                               object)
    IL_002d:  ldarg.0
    IL_002e:  ldstr      "_connectedPlayersByPlayerId"
    IL_0033:  ldfld      [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<class Util.NuID,class Networking.ServerController/ConnectedPlayer> Networking.ServerController::_connectedPlayersByPlayerId
    IL_0038:  callvirt   instance void Networking.NetworkBehaviour::LocalNetworkVariableChange(string,
                                                                                               object)
    IL_003d:  ret
  } // end of method ServerController::.ctor
```

The two fields look like this:

```
[NetworkVariable(SyncOnChange = false)]
private readonly Dictionary<ushort, ConnectedPlayer> _connectedPlayersByClientId = new
  Dictionary<ushort, ConnectedPlayer>();
```

```
[NetworkVariable(SyncOnChange = false)]
private readonly Dictionary<NuID, ConnectedPlayer> _connectedPlayersByPlayerId = new
  Dictionary<NuID, ConnectedPlayer>();
```

Any idea?

Comment: `box System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2...` -- that's not valid. Why are you trying to box a reference type?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I missed that. I updated my code (and the question) and tested again: Still same error (different offset).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `box System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary...`. You can't box a reference type.

The second problem is the `ldfld`. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldfld?view=net-7.0):

> The stack transitional behavior, in sequential order, is:
>
> 1. An object reference (or pointer) is pushed onto the stack.
> 2. The object reference (or pointer) is popped from the stack; the value of the specified field in the object is found.
> 3. The value stored in the field is pushed onto the stack.

In other words, `ldfld` needs to know the object to read the field from, and it consumes that object parameter from the stack.

So you need:

```
ldarg.0   // Load the 'this' for the method call
ldstr ... // Load the string to pass to the method
ldarg.0   // Load the 'this' for the ldfld
ldfld ... // Load the dictionary to pass to the method
callvirt ...
```

Comment: Those indeed where two errors. Still it didn't work. First when I replaced `callvirt` with `call` it started working. But why?

Comment: Are you sure? `callvirt` should behave almost identically to `call` here, except that `call` will null-check the receiver (which is why the compiler will emit it in this case)

Comment: I am sure. Checked it again.